# How to show in a table results based on my DataBase? Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have these 3 tables in my DB:

- Conductores: id_conductor, nombre_conductor
- Trayectos: id_trayecto, Trayecto, Origen, Destino, Horas_conduccion
- Viajes: id_viaje, id_conductor, id_trayecto, Salida, Llegada, Horas_conduccion, Disco, Semana

The table "Viajes" is the one in which I will insert the journeis of the truck drivers(conductor) every day, and I want to calculate the drive hours and rest hours for each truck driver in a table like this one:

[image: Tabla Resumen]

> The Code that I have to build this table is the following:

```
The connection to the data base obviously...
<?php
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Conductor</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Posicion Actual</b></td>";
// (etc.........)
echo "<td><b>Descansos 11 H.</b></td>";
echo "</tr>";

$sql="SELECT * FROM conductores ";
$resultado=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br($row["nombre_conductor"]) . "</td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  // (etc.........)
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

I know how to calculate columns but just for one truck driver, for instance, if I want the Current Position (Posicion Actual) for driver 1, I'll do:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT Destino FROM trayectos WHERE (SELECT MAX(id_viaje) FROM viajes WHERE id_conductor=1)");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo "Posición Actual = " . $row["Destino"];
```

Hours driving last week:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME (SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(Horas_conduccion))) as total FROM viajes WHERE id_conductor=1 AND semana=week(curdate())-1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo "horas semana anterior = " . $row["total"];
```

And so on with the rest.

So I want to do it automatically for each truck Driver, and cover the hole table.

Could you help me? I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: You need subqueries and joins

Comment: Yeah..but I don't know how..

Answer (score 0):

Get the ids of each conductor from the list of conductors and then pass it to the query and loop it.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT Destino FROM trayectos WHERE (SELECT MAX(id_viaje) FROM viajes WHERE id_conductor='.$conductor_id)");
```

Comment: Okay, I'll think how to do it! Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, let's code joins in php instead of in sql. Not that sql was designed to do joins...

Answer (score 0):

You will need a combination of subqueries and joins to combine all these data into a single query.

```
 SELECT c.*, t1.maxid, tr.Destino, t2.total FROM conductores c
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_conductor, MAX(id_viaje) maxid FROM viajes GROUP BY id_conductor) t1 on c.id_conductor = t1.id_conductor
 LEFT JOIN viajes v on t1.maxid=v.id_viaje
 LEFT JOIN trayectos tr on tr.id_trayecto = v.id_trayecto
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_conductor, SEC_TO_TIME (SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(Horas_conduccion))) as total
            FROM viajes
            GROUP BY id_conductor 
            WHERE semana=week(curdate())-1) t2 on c.id_conductor=t2.id_conductor
```

The 1st subquery retrieves the `max(id_viaje)` from `viajes` table by driver. Then I join again the `viajes` table to get the corresponding `id_trayecto` back and use that data to get the destination.

The 2nd subquery get the time summary by driver.

Comment: Yeah Shadow, both id's (id_conductor and id_trayecto) are the same as in "Viajes" table

I'll analize what you wrote.
Thank You!

Comment: Sorry, missed the table description at the beginning of your question. I'll update my code

Comment: No problem! Thanks again!